# Adding a self-signed client certificate to HAProxy for mutual-tls?

Tags: tls, certificates, linux, mutual, haproxy

I added the client cert into ca.pem as in

```
bind 0.0.0.0:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/asdf.hdavid.io.pem verify optional ca-file /etc/ssl/certs/ca.pem
http-request set-header X-SSL-Client-Verify        %[ssl_c_verify]
```

And then calling with `curl -v --key key.pem --cert cert.pem https://asdf.hdavid.io`

But I get X-SSL-Client-Verify as zero in the backend in both cases, when the client presents a valid certificate and when it presents a certificate not in haproxy trust

Actually it seems to work, with verify require haproxy properly blocks requests not coming from the certificate I trusted inside haproxy. But when I have verify optional. I always get ssl_c_verify as zero, why is that?

Comment: Make sure that `ca.pem` and `cert.pem` are actually the same. Make also sure that the certficate has basic constrains CA:true (check with `openssl x509 -in  cert.pem -text`). If still a problem please provide enough information so that the problem can be reproduced, especially the exact way `cert.pem` and `key.pem` were created or simply the full content of these files.

Comment: they are the same. updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But when I have verify optional. I always get ssl_c_verify as zero, why is that?

Because this means successful validation. From [the documentation of haproxy](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.0/configuration.html#7.3.4-ssl_c_verify):

> ssl_c_verify : integer
>  Returns the verify result error ID when the
> incoming connection was made over an SSL/TLS transport layer,
> otherwise **zero if no error is encountered**. Please refer to your SSL
> library's documentation for an exhaustive list of error codes.

This zero is basically `X509_V_OK` as documented in [openssl verify](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/verify.html).

> But I get X-SSL-Client-Verify as zero in the backend in both cases, when the client presents a valid certificate and when it presents a certificate not in haproxy trust

I cannot reproduce this. When the client presents a certificate which is not trusted the connection will fail since the verification fails:

```
$ curl ... -cert wrong.pem ...
...
* OpenSSL SSL_read: error:14094418:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown ca, errno 0
```

But when no certificate is presented the connection will succeed, since the client certificate is considered optional.

But it looks like you want the connection to actually succeed with the wrong certificate, but to forward the error upstream. And you also want to forward the information if a client certificate was used in the first place. In this case you might use something like this:

```
bind 0.0.0.0:443 ssl ... verify optional crt-ignore-err all ...
http-request set-header X-SSL-Client-Verify   %[ssl_c_verify]
http-request set-header X-SSL-Client-Used     %[ssl_c_used]
```

The `X-SSL-Client-Used` header will then be `1` if a client certificate was given. The `X-SSL-Client-Verify` will be `0` if no error happened during certificate validation, which includes the case that no certificate was given. Otherwise it will return the verification error.

Comment: I've updated my question, sorry my english was not helping me here.

Comment: @DavidHofmann: see updated answer